# std::sort only one dimension of a multi dimensional vector

Tags: c++, sorting, stdvector

I am trying to sort a multi dimensional vector and I am having a few problems along the way
if i use this code I have all of my int from vec[ ][ ][ ] ordered by vec[ ][5][0]
Is there any way i could order my vector vec based on the last dimension(vec[ ][ ][0] to vec[ ][ ][5])?

```
int main(){
    vector<vector<vector<int> > > vec (148995,vector<vector<int> >(7,vector <int>(6,0))); 
    order();
    order2();
}
bool comparison_function(const std::vector<std::vector<int> >& v1,
                     const std::vector<std::vector<int> >& v2) {

    return v1[5][0] > v2[5][0];
}

void order(){
     std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(),comparison_function);
}
bool comparison_function2(const std::vector<std::vector<int> >& v1,
                     const std::vector<std::vector<int> >& v2) {

    return v1[5][2] > v2[5][2];
}

void order2(){
     std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(),comparison_function2);
}
```

The way it works right now is if i call order() then order2(), all the ordering of order() is lost and everything is ordered by order2().

Ultimately I would like to have 6 order functions which could order the vector dimensions separatly using the third bracket of vec[ ][ ][x]

thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't sort the same vector with two different comparison functions. The second sort forget about the first sort.

You should use only one call to std sort but with a composed comparison function (like for the lexicographic order). Here is an example for 2 dimensional vector to give you the idea:

```
bool comparison_function(const std::vector<std::vector<int> >& v1,
                 const std::vector<std::vector<int> >& v2) {

    if (v1[5][0] != v2[5][0]) return v1[5][0] > v2[5][0];
    else                      return v1[5][1] > v2[5][1];
}
```